# SQL Grouping with Additional Checks

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata

I have a table with the following structure

| id | event_name | event_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1.1.2019 |
| 1 | b | 2.1.2019 |
| 1 | c | 2.3.2019 |
| 2 | a | 3.2.2020 |
| 2 | b | 5.1.2020 |
| 2 | c | 4.2.2020 |
| 3 | a | 1.2.2020 |
| 3 | b | 5.2.2020 |
| 3 | c | 3.2.2020 |
| 4 | a | 3.2.2020 |
| 4 | c | 4.2.2020 |

I'd like to group on the id, afterwards I have to check if the order of event_names matches the order of event_date like event_date for 'a' < event_date for 'b' < event_date for 'c'. Additionally I have to check, whether the event 'b' is in the table (if so the order doesn't matter anymore). This would result in a column 'event_check' with following values:

- "ok"  when event_date for 'a' < event_date for 'b' < event_date for 'c'
- "too early" when event_date for 'b' < event_date for 'a'
- "too late" when event_date for 'c' <  event_date for 'b'
- "missing b" when there's no event 'b' in a group

In this example this would result to

| id | event_check |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ok |
| 2 | too early |
| 3 | too late |
| 4 | missing b |

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @id'7238  Teradata 16.20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following SQL statement, it should work on most DBMS.

```
SELECT
  id,
  CASE 
    WHEN event_date_a < event_date_b AND event_date_b < event_date_c THEN 'ok'
    WHEN event_date_b < event_date_a THEN 'too early'
    WHEN event_date_c < event_date_b THEN 'too late'
    WHEN event_date_b IS NULL THEN 'missing b'
  END AS event_check
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id,
    MIN(CASE WHEN event_name = 'a' THEN event_date END) AS event_date_a,
    MIN(CASE WHEN event_name = 'b' THEN event_date END) AS event_date_b,
    MIN(CASE WHEN event_name = 'c' THEN event_date END) AS event_date_c
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY id
) agg
```

Comment: That's how I approached the problem, but I wasn't sure if it is the fastest way to solve it. Is there a performance boost to do the MIN(...) with an extra select instead of doing it in-line with 'Min(event a) < Min(event b)'

Comment: I don't think it affects performance. Check the query execution plan. Here is an example without subquery and comparing their plans  - [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4de6682eaa36199d9dce4f8f2be6c7b0)